# Need advice on Algorithm

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, if-statement

I have a code where I use two different functions for `2D` and `3D`. In a `for` loop over the list of coordinates, I would like call the functions respectively by checking the `dimensions`. However, checking the dimension with `if` for every coordinate is very inefficient, since dimension check is only once needed (at the beginning of the code).

For your info, the `2D / 3D functions` are in separate file and then list of coordinates are in a separate file.

Can anyone suggest a efficient way to call the appropriate function, by using only one check at the beginning of code for `dimensions`?

Pseudocode:
file1.cpp

```
readcoordinates();  //store the coordinates info;
for(number of coordinates)
   checkfunction(coordinates[i]); //function in file2.cpp
```

file2.cpp

```
checkfunction(coordinates[i]){
   //requires dimension info here for complicated checking,
   // which cannot be explained here.
   // Since entire list of coordinates is same dimension, multiple if checks can be avoided here

}
```

Comment: We're unlikely to be able to help you without seeing more context. Could you post your actual code here? Thanks!

Comment: Are the two functions doing what is essentially the same thing, but with different dimensionality?  If so, it's probably possible to generalize the function to accept n-dimensional coordinates.  If you post code, we can likely help with that, or better answer your question.

Comment: "...checking the dimension with if for every coordinate is very inefficient, since dimension check is only once needed (at the beginning of the code)" Then don't. If your coordinates are well defined, function overloads or template specializations for containers of 2D vs. 3D coords moves the "check" to compile-time and eliminates it entirely at run-time. Which method you choose is ultimately up to you.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, I thought about compile time. But, actually the code reads the input properties during runtime. Therefore, I know about the `dimensions` only during runtime.

Comment: @SathishKrishnan Your putting them *somewhere*. If in the end you have a vector of `Coord2D` vs. `Coord3D` you can easily dispatch that once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the number of dimensions a template parameter.  This allows you to avoid code duplication, but the compiler will get rid of ALL the dimension checks, creating a version of the code for 2-D and a separate one for 3-D, both getting fully optimized.

You can't provide template parameters at runtime, so then you need a dispatch function that dynamically checks the dimension, once, and calls either the 2-D or 3-D template instance.

An alternative to `if`-`else` or `switch` in the dispatch function, is to use virtual dispatch (each virtual implementation then calls the right template instantiation to do the actual work).

Answer (score 1):

In most situations like this, the key is to stop accessing your items through the List of all items.  Lists don't maintain order, and that limits you to a lot of checking location to see if the item needs processing.

You could, for example use a tree of items, and then zero in on the first item within the desired range in the X axis, and the last item within the desired range on that X axis, and process all items "in between".  With such a solution, you could maintain two ordered trees, on for the the X axis and one for the Y axis.

Or, you could build a data structure based on Geo-Hashing techniques.

In either case, you could filter out the items by coordinate quickly, and then pass them to other routines that don't do any coordinate based filtering (trusting that the filtering from outside is correct).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other suggestions (and assuming you are using these for some sort of 2D vs 3D math), you could also just treat everything as a 3D vector (the 2D vectors would just have a 0 for the Z-coordinate).  Then you are just implementing a single function, regardless of how many coordinates you have in your structure.